# TypeError in __iter__

Tags: python

```
def __init__(self, maximum, start=0, step=1):
        """Sets the maximum, start, and step"""
        try:
            self.maximum = math.ceil(maximum)
            self.start = math.ceil(start)
            self.step = math.ceil(step)
        except TypeError:
            return "Error, attributes must be of type int or float"
    def __iter__(self):
        """Iterates over the range"""
        return iter(range(self.start, self.maximum, self.step))
```

is the relevant code. Whenever I call, say:

```
j = crange.ChangeableRange(4)
list(j)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "crange.py", line 16, in __iter__
    return iter(range(self.start, self.maximum, self.step))
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Why? How do I fix this?

Comment: Joe, did Raymond Hettinger's answer solve your problem? (In case it wasn't perfectly clear, his point was that you need to give actual integer objects to `range`, not just floating-point values that happen to be integers, and `math.ceil` returns floating-point values in Python 2.) If it did, you should accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *range* function expects integers for arguments.  It looks like you've created a string for either *start*, *maximum*, or *step* with something like `self.maximum = int(math.ceil(maximum))`.

Also note that in Python 2, the *math.ceil* function returns a float value, so those would need to be converted to integers.

In Python 3, your code works fine:

```
>>> import math
>>> class ChangeableRange:
        def __init__(self, maximum, start=0, step=1):
            """Sets the maximum, start, and step"""
            try:
                self.maximum = math.ceil(maximum)
                self.start = math.ceil(start)
                self.step = math.ceil(step)
            except TypeError:
                return "Error, attributes must be of type int or float"
        def __iter__(self):
            """Iterates over the range"""
            return iter(range(self.start, self.maximum, self.step))


>>> j = ChangeableRange(4)
>>> print(list(j)) 
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This is probably the answer, we just can't tell for sure since you didn't post enough code

Comment: Agreed.  You must be setting those values somewhere else in your code.  If you want to try to track down where, you could always temporarily turn those values in to properties that check type on set and see what fails.  Actually, I'd recommend making those properties to begin with since you want to be sure they never get set to something that won't work with iter...